# How to display user input on one line in a palandrome assignment?

Tags: perl

In perl, I have to determine whether user input is a palindrome or not and it must display like this:

```
Enter in 7 characters: ghghghg #one line here #
Palindrome! #second line answer#
```

But instead this is what it does:

```
Enter in 7 characters: g #one line#
h #second line#
g #third line#
h #fourth line#
g #fifth line#
h #sixth line#
g  Palindrom

e! #seventh line#
```

My problem seems to be on the chomp lines with all the variables but I just can't figure out what to do and I've been at if for hours.  I need a simple solution, but have not progressed to arrays yet so need some simple to fix this. Thanks

And here is what i have so far, the formula seems to work but it keeps printing a new line for each character:

```
use strict; 
use warnings;

my ($a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $f, $g);
print "Enter in 7 characters:";

chomp ($a = <>); chomp ($b = <>); chomp ($c = <>); chomp ($d = <>); chomp ($e = <>); chomp ($f = <>); chomp ($g = <>);

if (($a eq $g) && ($b eq $f) && ($c eq $e) && ($d eq $d) && ($e eq $c) && ($f eq $b) && ($g eq $a))

{print "Palindrome! \n";}
else
{print "Not Palindrome! \n";}
```

Comment: `<>` reads a line (not a character). You should only be doing `<>` *once*.

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to determine if a word is the same backwards, may I suggest using [`reverse`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/reverse.html) and [`lc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/lc.html)?

```
chomp(my $word = <>);
my $reverse = reverse $word;

if (lc($word) eq lc($reverse)) {
    print "Palindrome!";
} else {
    print "Not palindrome!";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

print "Please enter 7 characters : ";

my $input = <>;    # Read in input
chomp $input;      # To remove trailing "\n"

# Season with input validation
warn 'Expected 7 characters, got ', length $input, ' instead'
  unless length $input == 7;

# Determine if it's palindromic or not

say   $input eq reverse $input
    ? 'Palindrome'
    : 'Not palindrome' ;
```

TIMTOWTDI for the recursion-prone:

```
sub is_palindrome {

    return 1 if length $_[0] < 2;   # Whole string is palindromic

    goto \&is_palindrome
      if substr $_[0], 0, 1, '' eq substr $_[0], -1, 1, ''; # Check next chars

    return;                          # Not palindromic if we reach here
}

say is_palindrome( 'ghghghg' ) ? 'Palindromic' : 'Not palindromic' ;
```

And [`perldoc perlretut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Recursive-patterns) for those who aren't :)

> **Recursive patterns**
>
> This feature (introduced in Perl 5.10) significantly extends the power
>   of Perl's pattern matching. By referring to some other capture group
>   anywhere in the pattern with the construct `(?group-ref)`, the pattern
>   within the referenced group is used as an independent subpattern in
>   place of the group reference itself. Because the group reference may
>   be contained within the group it refers to, it is now possible to
>   apply pattern matching to tasks that hitherto required a recursive
>   parser.
>
> To illustrate this feature, we'll design a pattern that matches if a
>   string contains a palindrome. (This is a word or a sentence that,
>   while ignoring spaces, interpunctuation and case, reads the same
>   backwards as forwards. We begin by observing that the empty string or
>   a string containing just one word character is a palindrome. Otherwise
>   it must have a word character up front and the same at its end, with
>   another palindrome in between.
>
> ```
> /(?: (\w) (?...Here be a palindrome...) \g{-1} | \w? )/x
> ```
>
> Adding `\W*` at either end to eliminate what is to be ignored, we
>   already have the full pattern:
>
> ```
> my $pp = qr/^(\W* (?: (\w) (?1) \g{-1} | \w? ) \W*)$/ix;
> for $s ( "saippuakauppias", "A man, a plan, a canal: Panama!" ){
>     print "'$s' is a palindrome\n" if $s =~ /$pp/;
> }
> ```

Comment: You should make a case-insensitive comparison.

Comment: @TLP : Strictly speaking, yes, but it doesn't look like the OP specified it

Comment: One of my requirements that I have to meet is to create my own way of determing whether it was a palandrome without using the reverse function.  So, from your comments, I'm only supposed to use <> once?

Comment: One of my requirements that I have to meet is to create my own way of determing whether it was a palandrome without using the reverse function and I have to use the formula with && and eq.  So, from your comments, I'm only supposed to use <> once?

Comment: @Rachel : Correct. Please tag questions related to assignments as `homework` next time.

Answer (score 1):

Perl is famous for its [TIMTOWTDI](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThereIsMoreThanOneWayToDoIt). Here are two more ways of doing it:

```
print "Enter 7 characters: ";
chomp(my $i= <STDIN>);

say "reverse: ",  pal_reverse($i) ? "yes" : "no";
say "regex: ", pal_regex($i) ? "yes" : "no";

sub pal_reverse {
    my $i = (@_ ? shift : $_);
    return $i eq reverse $i;
}

sub pal_regex {
    return (@_ ? shift() : $_) =~ /^(.?|(.)(?1)\2)$/ + 0;
}
```